# Can't access to foreign key properties using Entity Framework in Razor Pages project

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, razor-pages

I'm trying to display foreign key properties values using class that should have access to it:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.UserIssues)
{
    <div class="card scroll" style="width:22rem;">
        <div class="card-header p-4">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <div>
                    <p class="card-label mb-0"></p>
                    <h5>@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Case.CaseNumber)</h5>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a class="btn button-idle-add" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-title="Dodaj Pracownię" asp-route-id="@item.Id" asp-page="/Cases/AddLaboratory"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mt-3">
                <div>
                    <p class="card-input">@Html.DisplayFor(e => item.Case.Principal)</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="card-input">@Html.DisplayFor(e => item.Case.Date)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="m-1 p-3 card-lab">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(e => item.IssueNumber)</p>
                    <p class="pe-3 ps-3" style="border-radius:15px; background-color: palegreen;"></p>
                </div>
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(e => item.Specialist.Laboratory)</p>
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(e => item.Specialist.FullName)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IRepository<Issue> issueRepository;

    private readonly IRepository<Specialist> specialistRepository;

    public IndexModel(IRepository<Issue> issueRepository, IRepository<Specialist> specialistRepository)
    {
        this.issueRepository = issueRepository;
        this.specialistRepository = specialistRepository;
    }

    public List<Issue> AllIssues { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        var loggedUser = specialistRepository.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Login == User.Identity.Name);

        UserIssues = issueRepository.GetAll().Where(i => i.Specialist.Id == loggedUser.Id).ToList();

        return Page();
    }
}
```

So for Specialist it works just fine:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(e => item.Specialist.FullName)
```

But for the Case it doesn't work, nothing is displayed:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Case.CaseNumber)
```

Here are my models for Entity Framework setup:

```
    public class Case
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Uzupełnij pole")]
        public string CaseNumber { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Uzupełnij pole")]
        public string Principal { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Uzupełnij pole")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

                [Required(ErrorMessage = "Uzupełnij pole")]
                public string Date { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Issue> Issues { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Issue
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

                public string Comment { get; set; }

                [Required(ErrorMessage = "Uzupełnij pole")]
                public string IssueNumber { get; set; }

        public Case Case { get; set; }

                public Specialist Specialist { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Specialist : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        public string Login { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Laboratory { get; set; }

        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return FirstName + " " + LastName;
            }
        }

        public ICollection<Issue> Issues { get; set; }
    }
```

Is my Entity Framework setup wrong? How can I display property values for the Case entity?

Comment: Do you use Include in your repository query? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) Perhaps you can show the relevant code?

Comment: Provide your db query for the view Model

Answer (score 0):

Using Entity Framework in case you want to get a specialist with id e775704b-5298-4173-82c8-c15d884e0695 and include the issues for this specialist you can use the include method in order to get the associated data.

```
Specialist? specialist = context.Specialists.Where(m => m.Id == "e775704b-5298-4173-82c8-c15d884e0695").Include(m => m.Issues).FirstOrDefault();
if (specialist != null)
{
    foreach (var issue in specialist.Issues)
    {
        string issueNumber = issue.IssueNumber;
    }
}
```

You can do the same thing for the entire list like this.

```
List<Specialist> specialists = context.Specialists.Include(m => m.Issues).ToList();
foreach (var specialist in specialists)
{
    foreach (var issue in specialist.Issues)
    {
        string issueNumber = issue.IssueNumber;
    }
}
```